# Efficient sql query to find a composite key in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following problem:

Suppose there is a table `EMP` with employees data.
The columns that we are interested in are `DeptID` and `ManagerID`.

I have a list of (say) 50 records in the following format -

deptId1 , managerid1  so on

What is the most efficient way of doing this in sql?

For example, if I was only searching by `ManagerID`, I could have done the following:

```
 Select * from EMP where ManagerID in (id1, id2, ..., id50);
```

However in case of pair, I am forced to execute the following query 50 times:

```
 select * from EMP where ManagerID = Mid1
                        AND DeptID = deptid;
```

EDIT :

One approach I came up with:

If I change the report to have DeptID+ManagerID

I can do something like this:

```
 WITH TEMPTABLE AS
 select * from EMP where 
                (DeptID + ManagerID) IN ( sumID1 , sumID2.....)
 select * from TEMPTABLE where ManagerID = Mid1
                        AND DeptID = deptid;
```

Do you think this can be faster?

More importantly can we somehow use an index on (DeptID + ManagerID)?

Comment: `Select * from EMP where (ManagerID, DeptId) in ((id1, dep1), (id2, dep2),...)` Oracle should support row contructors

Comment: Unfortunately, this query gives error: invalid relational operator

Comment: Try: `Select * 
from EMP 
where (ManagerID, DeptId) in (SELECT id1 AS col1, dep1 as col2 FROM  dual 
                              UNION ALL SELECT id2, dep2  FROM  dual)`

Comment: @lad2025 scratch that, this actually works. Let me think why we were unable to use this approach.

Comment: `Select * from EMP where (ManagerID, DeptId) = ANY ((id1, dep1), (id2, dep2),...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `= ANY`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbcd1/2/0)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP 
WHERE (ManagerID, DeptId) = ANY ((1,1), (2,4));
```

or `IN` + `subquery`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP 
WHERE (ManagerID, DeptId) IN (SELECT 1 AS col1, 1 AS col2 FROM dual 
                              UNION ALL SELECT 2,4        FROM dual)
```

or `CTE/subquery` + `JOIN`:

```
WITH cte(ManagerId, DeptID) AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS ManagerId, 2 AS DeptID FROM dual 
   UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4              FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM EMP e
JOIN cte c
  ON e.ManagerId = c.ManagerId
 AND e.DeptId = c.DeptId;
```

or simple `IN` as in comment:

**[SqlFiddleDemo_IN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbcd1/3/0)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP 
WHERE (ManagerID, DeptId) IN ((1,1), (2,4));
```

**EDIT:**

Combining as you proposed `(DeptID + ManagerID) IN ( sumID1 , sumID2.....)` is not good idea for example `(1+5) = (3+3)`. You will get inaccurate results.

Comment: I went through the original code, 1 year old, so forgive me for not giving the correct problem here. I will post that problem in a separate question as it will make a mess of things and hopefully someone would be able to suggest an elegant approach. I will also make a mention of that here.

Comment: Also, just one point, if you look closely in my suggested approach, I am building a temporary table (TEMPTABLE) of accuarate + inaccurate records, and then running the final query on this set. Something like hashing.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  *
from
  emp
where
  (managerid, departmentid) in (
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3)
  )
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but @lad2025 replied first (as a comment) so marking his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to load the list into a database table? Then you could JOIN your EMP table to it on the two conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP e
JOIN DEPT_MGR d
ON e.ManagerID = d.ManagerID
AND e.DeptID = d.DeptID
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean creating a new table in data model? You can't change the data model.